# Rails: setting column default to created_at timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, timestamp, default

I am using a Postgres DB with Rails v4.1.6

I have a table with a `start_time` column.

I want the `start_time` column to be non null and have a default value of the timestamp that will be the value in `created_by`.

My understanding is that the timestamp value for `created_by` (and `updated_at`) are created by Rails and not enforced by the DB (please let me know if this is wrong). If there a way to match these two columns up? Is there a way to have the DB enforce it?

My only solution right now is to use a before_create filter (but I think there would be inconsistencies between the two values).

Comment: Have you considered using `after_create` callback to update the `start_time` attribute by setting it equal to `created_at` value ?

Comment: I have to agree with @Alireza in how to handle this situation. The way to have it database enforced would be to make a custom create method in your model and call that each time you do a create (which would be much harder) and that would satisfy the non-null requirement in your schema.

Comment: Do you need the two columns to be ***exactly*** the same instant? Will `start_time` later change?

Comment: @Alireza and nikkon226 thanks for your response. after_create is probably my best options then. 

because the order of operation in a save flow has the validations before the save, is there any way to have a validation on start_time? My guess is not.

Comment: @Substantial my goal is to make them exactly the same

Comment: @Sarindipity Will `start_time` later change or will it stay the same over the life of the record?

Comment: @Substantial it could change in the future. I definitely cannot put the constraint that it must remain the same for the life of the record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to thank @Alireza and @nikkon226 for perspective on this question.

The solution I am using now is to modify the start_time in a before_create filter. In before_create (at least in Rails v4.1.6) the timestamps have already been set. It is better to modify the record in before_create rather than after_create because it saves us at least 1 save call.

Of course with this solution I no longer can put a validation of presence for start_time because validation happens before save/create.

If anyone has a better solution please share.

Comment: Interesting to know that the timestamps are already set in `before_create` callback